# How to merge cells in jqGrid 4.0

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've been trying to "merge" cells in a jqGrid, that is, I want to make cells for specific rows have a colspan=2 (or more). So far I've been able to get the borders to work properly using the **cellattr** option in the column model with something like this:

```
colModel = { name: "a", width=50, 
             cellattr: function(rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                          if (rowId < 5) { return 'sytle="border-right:0px"'; } },

             name: "b", width=50, 
             cellattr: function(rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                          if (rowId < 5) { return 'sytle="border-left:0px"'; } } };
```

This just removes the border for the cells that I want to merge (a & b up to line 5).  But if I add text to any of these boxes text-align will obviously not work properly and the text just gets cut off if it is larger than 50 pixels.

I could do some crazy thing where I do center-align by cutting all the text in half and add each half to column "a" and "b" under right-align and left-align respectively.  However, there seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: three step
try see there
http://bbs.blueidea.com/thread-3067461-1-1.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find your question very interesting, so +1 from me.

It seems to me that the usage of `colspan=2` is what you really need. To have the same number of the columns in the rows having `colspan=2` I suggest to hide the next `<td>` element in the row:

```
{
    name:'a',index:'a', width:50,
    cellattr: function(rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
        if (Number(rowId) < 5) { return ' colspan=2' }
    }
},
{
    name:'b',index:'b', width:50,
    cellattr: function(rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
        if (Number(rowId) < 5) { return ' style="display:none;"' }
    }
}
```

I tested the implementation only a few time, but it seems to work:

[image]

The demo you can see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridCellMerge.htm).

**UPDATED**: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294020/315935) shows how can be used `rowspan` attribute in jqGrid.

Comment: Oleg. I have a requirement to merge the column in the footerrow. Is this possible in jqGrid or do you have any solution. Here is my link--  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190756/how-to-merge-the-footer-rows-column-in-jqgrid

Comment: @BabuArumugam: I'v already answered your question, but I suggested to use a little other technique.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's not supported right now.  They say "near future".

http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1184