# jqGrid Editing – override logic to define cell value

Tags: jqgrid

Quotation from [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules) for checkbox:

> defines a checkbox; when the value is Yes, the checkbox becomes
>   checked, otherwise it is unchecked. This value is passed as a
>   parameter to the editurl.
>
> If in editoptions, the value property is not set, jqGrid searches for
>   the following values (false|0|no|off|undefined) in order to construct
>   the checkbox. If the cell content does not contain one of these
>   values, then the value attribute becomes the cell content and offval
>   is set to off.

I use form editing and want take value for checkbox not from cell content, but from attribute **data-val**, which I define myself on **loadComplete** event handler.

before loadComplete:

```
<td aria-describedby="data_grid_col1" title="0" style="" role="gridcell">0</td>
```

after loadComplete:

```
<td aria-describedby="data_grid_col1" title="0" style="" role="gridcell" data-val="0">Some content like NO</td>
```

Is there some event, or some another way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change content of cell you should use custom formatters. If you need set some attributes on the cell you should use `cellattr` callback.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625959/315935) demonstrates setting of `colspan` attribute, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294020/315935) sets `colspan`. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408355/315935) demonstrates setting of `title` attribute. In the same way you can set *any other* attribute on the cells (`<td>` elements).

Usage of `loadComplete` is less effective. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935) for more information.

Comment: thank you for tips! I'll try to use custom formatters instead of **loadComplete**, but problem is in broken binding for checkbox on **edit form**. jqGrid use `"editoptions": { "value": "1:0" }` from colModel and exactly these values should be set as cell content.

Comment: @eLVik: I don't understand what you mean under "broken binding". I could see that you used `data-val` attribute **on `<td>`** and so I wrote my answer where I suggested to use `cellattr` to do this. I don't understand which relation has checkbox to your question. If you defined custom formatter and unformatter then form editing will use the function for get data from *the cell content* and for setting the *the cell content*. If you would use `data-val` attribute not on  `<td>`, but on some its child element (`<span>` or `<div>`) then you can use custom formatter/unformatter.

Comment: Thanks, @Oleg! **unformat** and **formatter** functions solved my issue!