# Setting data attribute on each row of a jqgrid table

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid and I'm trying to add a data- attribute to each tr. I'm firing the loadComplete event, but I'm unsure of how to modify each row. Any code samples?

Comment: Can't you use a custom formatter for that cell?

Comment: I want it on the tr itself - not the cell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `rowattr` to assign *any* additional attribute to `<tr>` elements (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625959/315935) for code examples). For example you can use

```js
rowattr: function (rd) {
    return {"data-mydata": JSON.stringify(rd)};
}
```

to save full input row data as `data-mydata` attribute. I recommend you to use ``` rowattr``in combination with ```gridview: true` option to have the best performance results ()

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Rahul_.htm) uses above `rowattr` cade and you can see that rows of grid have additional `data-mydata` attribute:

[image]

Comment: How would I handle spaces? When I do the following: `return { "data-delete-name": rd.name };` and rd.name has a space, it only includes the first word.

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, I set the first column of grid by an identity. And in all my cases, id of each data row of my grids is the value of that identity column.

jqGrid column:

```
colModel: [
{
name:'ID',
label:'...',
width:1,
index:'ID'
...
```

Rendered :

```
<tr role="row" id="10777" ... > // in retrieved data: ID = 10777
```

So, if you have similar declarations like me, this could be a useful selector for you and you can simply add your data- attrib to these rows like this:

```
$('#trId').prop('data-whatever', 'value');
```

And if you want the above line to be performed automatically to all rows, you should change it slightly and put it into the `gridComplete` event of your grid:

```
gridComplete: function() { $("tr[role='row']").prop('data-whatever', 'value'); }
```

Comment: Sure, having the ID there is very helpful. However, I still have other data elements that I would like to place in a data attribute on the row. I know jqGrid has other ways to get at that data, but I'm changing out a custom grid for a jqGrid so there's existing functionality/styles that I'm still trying to take advantage of.

Comment: But where do I put that selector? In the loadComplete event? And how do I call it?

Comment: Great, now how would I append values from the dataset?