# jqgrid 4.5.4 formatter:select not working for duplicate values in combo box

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 4.5.4 to build a jqGrid. I have problem in editing combobox. 
My combobox has city names. 
In combo box there are two cities with same name but different key values. While editing a row in jqgrid dropdown populated with the city of different kay value. I used `formatter:'select'`. But it is not working.

My code is as follows ::

```js
var jQuery = $.noConflict();
var lastSel = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        // The link we are accessing.
        url: <%= "'" +url_1.toString()+"'"%>,
        // The type of request.
        type: "get",
        // The type of data that is getting returned.
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data){
            jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
                url:<%= "'" +url.toString()+"'"%>,
                datatype:"json",
                mtype:"POST",
                colNames:['localityId','City','Locality'],
                colModel:[
                    {
                            name:'localityId',
                            index:'localityId',
                            width:240,
                            key:true,
                            editrules:{edithidden:false, required:true},
                            editable:true,
                            hidden:true
                    },
                    {
                            name:'cityId',
                            index:'cityId',
                            width:240,
                            editable:true, 
                            edittype:'select',
                            formatter:'select',
                            sortable:true,
                            editrules:{ required:true},
                            editoptions: {  
                                value:  data                                            
                            }       
                    },
                    {
                            name:'locality',
                            index:'locality', 
                            width:240,
                            sortable:true,
                            editable:true, 
                            edittype:'text'
                    }
                ],
                rowNum:10, 
                rowList:[10,20,30], 
                pager: '#pager2', 
                sortname: 'locality',
                editurl:<%= "'" +url_edit.toString()+"'"%>,
                viewrecords: true,
                multiselect: true, 
                sortorder: "desc", 
                caption:"Locality Master"
            });

            jQuery("#list2").navGrid(
                                      '#pager2',
                                      {add:true, edit:true, del:true},
                                      {},
                                      {},
                                      {},
                                      {}
                                    );
    });
});
```

If formatter='select' is removed then cityId is shown on screen and then if the row is edited then correct city is selected in dropdown. What is the problem with formatter='select' and editoption.

Comment: Could you return an example of the `data` which you use in `editoptions.value`? Moreover you can find [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) the description of approach where the `editoptions.value` are set by `setColProp` inside of `beforeProcessing`. In the case one need just place the response from `url_1` as the part of the response on `url`. It simplify the code and reduce the number of Ajax requests.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. Data set for editoptions.value is json object is in following format             {"1":"Arambol","2":"Mollem","3":"Bicholim","4":"Mapusa","35":"Mollem"} So for city 'Mollem' it is creating problem in edit.

Comment: Could you provide some test data returned from `url:<%= "'" +url.toString()+"'"%>`? Two rows with different value, but the same text in the select will be enough. Do you tried to use have `editoptions.value` defined as string: `"1:Arambol;2:Mollem;3:Bicholim;4:Mapusa;35:Mollem"`?

Comment: I have tried with string but it is not succesful.Data obtained for url is as follows:             [{"localityId":"1","locality":"Budtala","city":"Mollem","cityId":2},
{"localityId":"5","locality":"mapusa hill new","city":"Mapusa","cityId":4},
{"localityId":"6","locality":"mapusa tal","city":"Mapusa","cityId":4},
{"localityId":"3","locality":"Mollem sr","city":"Mollem","cityId":35}]

Comment: I have to go away. I will be able to continue some hours later.

Comment: @Oleg what i observed that when formatter='select' is given it displays city name corresponding to its id correctly on jqGrid but on edit when city combobox is populated then it compares cityname in <option value="cityId">cityName</option>   instead of cityId. So it shows wrong selected value. What is wrong with code. Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem which you described. The problem is clear: jqGrid use `formatter: "select"` which replaces the values (like `2`, `4`, `35`) to the strings which will be saved in the grid cell (in `<td>`). The cell have no information about the original value of select.

[image]

So it just calls unformatter of the formatter "select" at the initializing of the form editing. If you have *the same text* for different select values then the standard unformatter can't distinguish both "Mollem" having originally different values `2` and `35`. So the unformatter returns always the first found value: `2.

I don't familiar in geography of India, but I can imagine that there are exists really two different city wit the same name. I would recommend you to have different texts for selects so that the user can clear see which one "Mollem" are chosen. On the other side one could include different "Mollem" under different option group (`<optgroup>`). In the case the problem will be exactly like in your original question.

I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18313154/315935) how one can assign `data` attributes to the row (`<tr>`) to save custom additional information. I suggest to use the same approach with the cells (`<td>`). I want to have the grid looks like

[image]

The corresponding code is very easy. One can define `cityId` column something like

```js
{
    name: "cityId", formatter: "select", edittype: "select",
    editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { value: data },
    cellattr: function (rowId, value, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
        return ' data-val="' + rawObject.cityId + '"';
    },
    unformat: function (cellText, options, $cell) {
        return String($cell.data("val"));
    }
}
```

Additionally I overwrite the default unformatter of `formatter: select` with my custom implementation which get the value directly from `data-val` attribute: `String($cell.data("val"))`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Man.htm) (you can compare it with [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Man0.htm) with original problem) uses additionally `dataUrl: "ManOptGroup.htm"` with `ManOptGroup.htm`:

```html
<select>
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option value="1" title="Arambol (Group 1)">Arambol</option>
        <option value="2" title="Mollem (Group 1)">Mollem</option>
        <option value="3" title="Bicholim (Group 1)">Bicholim</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option value="4" title="Mapusa (Group 2)">Mapusa</option>
        <option value="35" title="Mollem (Group 2)">Mollem</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

It improve the visibility of the select only to make easier to distinguish both `Mollem`. The resulting Edit form looks now like

[image]