# jqgrid in edit form select element's selected value from cell value

Tags: select, jqgrid, selectedvalue

Problem is if select element has options with same "text" but different values, in edit form select element's selected value is set wrong. I think selected value of the element is constructed by cell's text, not value.

I tried like this,

```
....
formatter:'select', 
edittype:'select',
editoptions{value:"1:Blue;2:Red;3:Green;4:Blue"}
....
```

If selected item is value=1, when open edit form value=4 may be selected.

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19601190/315935).

Comment: @Oleg smart technique, it works! thank you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqgrid 4.5.4 formatter:select not working for duplicate values in combo box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586427/jqgrid-4-5-4-formatterselect-not-working-for-duplicate-values-in-combo-box)