# jqGrid show a large column as a row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

We are using `struts 2 jquery grid 3.7.0` plugin which uses `jqGrid 4.6.0`

The grid has one column which has very large data, is it possible to show this large column as a row.

Like below

[image: A table with one large]

Although it seems like grouping but it is not.

I wonder if it is possible?!

I try `formatter` but all returned data from a `formatter` is keep in a cell.

Answer (score 1):

The `formatter` allows to set `innerHTML` of the cells only. You should use `cellattr` instead of `formatter` to set `colspan` attribute on `<td>` elements of the first column and the attribute `style="display:none;"` on `<td>` elements of the next three column. I recommend you to look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625959/315935) for more details.

One more alternative option, which you can consider, is changing the CSS rules applied on the cells. You can use `white-space: pre-wrap` (or `white-space: normal`) to wrap the information inside of one cell.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I just posted a similar question and tried a fix in this answer that did not work. Any progress on actual answer? thanks!