# Show column value on a separate row in Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, html-table, jqgrid

I looked here and couldn't find an answer how to do this with Jqgrid. In pure html, this would be colspan. I have 7 columns and the last one is long comment that needs to be shown on a separate line as this:

```
col 1 | col 2 | col3 | col 4 | col 5 | col6
Col7 blah blah blah
```

This will repeat for every record in the data set. Is there a way to achieve this in Jqgrid?

Comment: If you need just use `colspan` then you can use `cellattr` to set `colspan` on the left most cell of the group and to set `style="display:none;"` on other columns of the group (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5625959/315935)). On the other side you write about "needs to be shown on a separate line". I'm not sure, that I understand what you mean, because wrapping of data to the next line is impossible in the grid, at least not using `colspan` attribute.

Comment: It would be good it you post more details, about your jqGrid code (jqGrid version, how you fill the data, test data for a row of data and which look of grid you need to have).

Comment: Ok thanks Oleg, I will be switching to reg html as I need a separate line for this one.